# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'products' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, commerce.js

I am creating an E-Commerce web shop following a tutorial.

I would like to display the products that I fetch from an API.

There's an error in my code:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'products' of undefined
```

at line:

```js
const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
```

in `App.js`.

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { commerce } from "./lib/commerce";
import { Products, Navbar } from "./components";

const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();

    setProducts(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  console.log(products);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Products />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**UPDATE**

Contents of `./lib/commerce.js`:

```js
import Commerce from '@chec/commerce.js';
export const commerce = new Commerce(process.env.REACT_APP_CHEC_PUBLIC_KEY, true);
```

Comment: The error is telling you `products` is undefined.  So you need to look at `commerce` to see why?.

Comment: `commerce` is undefined, you need to track down why?..  Looking at your import & export it looks Ok, it's not something silly like you have not yet saved `./lib/commerce`,  I've done that a few times.. :)

Comment: could it be an error with returning the  promise since iwas fetching a response from  await which was the API call to commerce instance since it was to be called as a function to return a promise could it be an issue with returning the promise?

Comment: yes @JanezKuhar i followed the link it solved my problem i disconnect the connection with .env file and just add the public key to commerce.js. as from a post in the link thank you